# How to check if functions are integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Consider two functions

$$
\int_0^1 \frac{1}{e^x-1} dx 
$$

and

$$
\int_0^1 \frac{1}{(e^x-1)^2} dx
$$

How to check if these functions are integrable?

Comment: You could calculate $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{e^x - 1} dx$ and find $[\log(1-e^x)-x]_{0}^{1}$. Now insert $1$ and $0$ - what happens?

Answer (score 3):

Since the function 
$$
x \longmapsto\frac{1}{e^x-1}
$$
is continuous on $(0,1]$, a potential convergence problem, concerning the integral, is for $x$ near $0$.

We have
$$
\frac{1}{e^x-1} \sim_{0^+} \frac1x
$$ thus your integral $\displaystyle \int_0^1 \frac{1}{e^x-1} dx$ is divergent as  $\displaystyle \int_0^1 \frac{1}{x} dx$ is divergent.

In the same manner, we have
$$
\frac{1}{(e^x-1)^2} \sim_{0^+} \frac1{x^2}
$$ giving the divergence of $\displaystyle \int_0^1 \frac{1}{(e^x-1)^2} dx$ as  $\displaystyle \int_0^1 \frac{1}{x^2} dx$ is divergent.